# Took a Consumer Google Glass out of storage and now it won't hold a charge(?)

Tags: google-glass

This Google Glass has been in it's bag for a couple of years; It's the consumer version with the little nose rests and no apparent model number or identification. Here's a commercial picture of the model I have: https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2014/11/google-glass-100528641-medium.idge.jpg

I took it out and plugged it in to a known good USB cable and a known good 5v USB charger (that is, *not* the cable and charger from Google).

The light next to the switch comes on when I plug it in but turns off within 2 seconds. I left it charging overnight, and I can't get it to turn on or reset or factory reset.

I don't know for sure whether it is taking a charge and something else is wrong, or if it isn't charging due to a cable or charger incompatibility.

I've Googled about this and can't find any advice other than how to turn on (nothing happens), reset (nothing happens), or factory reset (nothing happens). Are there any other suggestions from people working with these devices?

Alternatively, does anybody have the spec for a replacement battery? The tear-downs  spec it at 570 mAh but don't mention the voltage.

Comment: Do you know what kind of batteries it has? Because I believe the various flavors of lithium battery have issues when discharged too far (as in sitting for many years in a box), and the controller will refuse to do anything with them if they've entered that state for safety reasons.

Comment: @MichaelKohne - no, I don't. That's why I tried to describe it as unambiguously as possible. Since there is no evident battery compartment and no way to get at or change the battery, it may not be a user-replaceable battery.

Comment: Based on a teardown I found, destructive force was needed to get at the battery. They found that "Google Glass is powered by a single-cell lithium-polymer battery rated at 2.1 watt-hours (570 mAh). " [https://www.extremetech.com/computing/158297-google-glass-teardown-futuristic-on-the-outside-thoroughly-underwhelming-on-the-inside]

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Because I want to develop on it but can't until I can turn it on?